# Embed Responsive YouTube Video with in line CSS

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, embed

I don't have access to my css and would like to embed a responsive YouTube video with in line CSS...

Is this possible? and could you please provide the div snippet?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nothing complicated, check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gwfttfze/

```
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

## edit

(based on first comment)
Use classes that are already defined in your css

```
<div class="product__video">
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dfSk1c6SzKw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... I added the the code from fiddle but the video is full width on the page (second video on page) http://goo.gl/R42k8F I would like it the same size as other video on page.

Comment: i saw the code of that page, and since you cannot edit the css, i recommend you to use those class that are already defined. For example, take a look at the first video and you'll see this structure:

<div class="product__video">
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe...></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: looks good now! if you want to change the color you can edit it inline like this


<div class="product__video" style="background-color: #FFF">

Comment: thanks again... how do I set answer to good? I can't see where